# How to download different sizes of an image from Twitter?

Tags: json, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using the Twitter Streaming API to get images included in tweets, and show them in my Android app. The media object which represents the image contains a media_url field that is a direct link to the image, and a JSON objects named sizes which contains the different sizes available for that image. The question is, how can I get such resized images? I want to download the thumbnail directly from Twitter, and since the sizes object contains a thumb field it should be possible, but how? I already tried to concat ?size=thumb to the media_url but it didn't work.
Media object example:

```
{"id":897839774635053000,"id_str":"897839774635053056","indices":
[75,98],"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHXEhKBW0AAKhf3.jpg",
"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHXEhKBW0AAKhf3.jpg",
"url":"https://REMOVED/4NcW6720Zj","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/4NcW6720Zj",
"expanded_url":
"https://twitter.com/darioolly/status/897840123924164608/photo/1",
"type":"photo",

"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},
         "medium":{"w":720,"h":711,"resize":"fit"},
         "small":{"w":680,"h":672,"resize":"fit"},
         "large":{"w":720,"h":711,"resize":"fit"}}}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can retrieve the media in different sizes by appending a colon + the size key, as specified [here](https://www.hitchhq.com/twitter/activities/entities-in-objects-twitter-developers-592c37f4da47466389006192)

> We support different sizes: thumb, small, medium and large. The media_url defaults to medium but you can retrieve the media in different sizes by appending a colon + the size key (for example: http://pbs.twimg.com/media/A7EiDWcCYAAZT1D.jpg:thumb ). Each available size comes with three attributes that describe it: w : the width (in pixels) of the media in this particular size; h : the height (in pixels) of the media in this particular size; resize : how we resized the media to this particular size (can be crop or fit )